# Intermediate Django 2.0 admin action page not displaying

Tags: django, django-admin

I have created an update custom admin action and want to ask for update confirmation by going to a new page before the update action is finalised.

Below is the code for various files:
admin.py`

```
class ProfileHolderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [field.attname for field in ProfileHolder._meta.fields]
    actions = ['update_verified']

    def update_verified(self, request, querySet):
        users_verified=querySet.update(verified='y')
        views.update_confirmation(request)
        self.message_user(request,"No. of users verified = %s" %str(users_verified))

    update_verified.short_description = "Mark selected users as verified"

admin.site.register(ProfileHolder, ProfileHolderAdmin)`
```

Code in views.py:

```
 def update_confirmation(request):
          return render(request,'Profile/confirm_update.html', context=None)
```

Code in confirm_update.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Confirm Update</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="admin.py" method="post">
        <p>
            Are you sure you want to update the verification status of selected users?
        </p>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_status" />
        <input type="submit" name="apply" value="Update status"/>
    </form>



</body>
</html>
```

The path to the html file is:
website_name\Profile\templates\Profile\confirm_update.html

Profile is the name of my app and website_name is the directory name.

When I carry out the update function, the status is being correctly updated but the intermediate update page is not showing.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your admin action currently returns `None` which means the admin will take care of redirecting back to the normal change list page.

In order to render the page you need to return the response you get from `update_confirmation`. Of course you first want to render the page and then run the queryset update. For that you need to find a way to tell the two calls apart (e.g. by adding a POST parameter `confirmed`).

```
def update_verified(self, request, querySet):
    if request.POST.get('confirmed') is None:
        return views.update_confirmation(request)
    users_verified=querySet.update(verified='y')
    self.message_user(request,"No. of users verified = %s" %str(users_verified))
```